# python - pass dataframe column as argument in apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
In[1]: df = DataFrame({"A": ['I love cooking','I love rowing'], "B": [['cooking','rowing'],['cooking','rowing']]})
```

Thus the output that I get is:

```
In[2]: df
Out[1]: 
            A                  B
0  I love cooking  [cooking, rowing]
1   I love rowing  [cooking, rowing]
```

I want to create a 'C' column where I count the number of occurrences of elements of 'B' in 'A'.

The function I create is:

```
def count_keywords(x,y):
    a = 0
    for element in y:
        if element in x:
            a += 1
return a
```

and then do:

```
df['A'].apply(count_keywords,args=(df['B'],))
```

In this case, I am passing the entire pandas dataseries as argument, so the element of the dataseries df['B'] is obviously a list, not a string (which in turn is the element of the list).

So I get:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

However, if I adjust the function so that:

```
def count_keywords(x,y): 
    a = 0
    for element in y:
        for new_element in element:
            if new_element in x:
                a += 1
    return a
```

and then do:

```
In[3]: df['A'].apply(count_keywords,args=(df['B'],))
```

the output is:

```
Out[2]: 
0    2
1    2
```

Because the function loops through every element in the pandas series and then through every element in the list.

How can I get the function to just check, per dataframe row, the element of series df['B'] against the element in series df['A'], so the output is:?

```
Out[2]: 
0    1
1    1
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you could do this is by using a set intersection to calculate the size. In theory this may be faster then iterating over the elements, since `set` is sort of designed for this kind of thing:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x.B).intersection(set(x.A.split()))), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `apply` over the other axis.

```
def count_keywords(row): 
    counter = 0
    for e in row['B']:
        if e in row['A']:
            counter += 1
    row['C'] = counter
    return row

df2 = df.apply(count_keywords,axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
           A                B           C
0   I love cooking  [cooking, rowing]   1
1   I love rowing   [cooking, rowing]   1
```

Then df2['C'] should give you the 1,1 series you mention.

Comment: great piece of advice vmg, I see that you pass the row instead of the column. makes a lot of sense.